# Bootstrap - three equal columns doesn't change line on 'a' element

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, row

I have some iframes (YouTube videos) and I want to put a link over the iframe. What I want to do is to place every link exactly over the iframe, but this is happening only for the first row (the first 3 iframes), while the others (4th link and beyond) it's  been placing next to third link.

Here is the code

```js
$(".fancybox")
  .attr('rel', 'gallery')
  .fancybox({
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    nextEffect: 'none',
    prevEffect: 'none',
    padding: 0,
    margin: [20, 60, 20, 60] // Increase left/right margin
  });

$('iframe').each(function() {
  var source = $(this).attr('src');
  $(this).attr('src', source + "&showinfo=0&rel=0&controls=2");
});

$('iframe').addClass('col-xs-12 col-md-4');

$('iframe').attr('href', '#');

var width = $('iframe').width();


$('iframe').css({
  'height': 0.6 * width + 'px'
});

var height = $('iframe').height();

$('p').each(function() {
  $(this).prepend('<a href="' + $(this).find('iframe').attr('src') + '" class="wrapper col-xs-12 col-md-4 fancybox fancybox.iframe"><a/>');
})

//$('.wrapper').width(width);
$('.wrapper').height(height);
```

```css
.entry-content p {
  margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}
.entry-content p iframe {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  float: left !important;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-nav {
  width: 60px;
}
.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-nav span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.1;
}
.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-nav:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content-left-wrap col-md-12">
    <div class="entry-content">
      <p>
        <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bctaf7alxpE?feature=oembed&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" href="#" style="height: 204px;"></iframe>
      </p>
      <p>
        <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bctaf7alxpE?feature=oembed&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" href="#" style="height: 204px;"></iframe>
      </p>
      <p>
        <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bctaf7alxpE?feature=oembed&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" href="#" style="height: 204px;"></iframe>
      </p>
      <p>
        <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bctaf7alxpE?feature=oembed&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" href="#" style="height: 204px;"></iframe>
      </p>
      <p>
        <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bctaf7alxpE?feature=oembed&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" href="#" style="height: 204px;"></iframe>
      </p>
      <p>
        <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bctaf7alxpE?feature=oembed&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" href="#" style="height: 204px;"></iframe>
      </p>
      <p>
        <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bctaf7alxpE?feature=oembed&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" href="#" style="height: 204px;"></iframe>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can alse find a snippet at https://jsfiddle.net/vg734x3u/1/ and see the result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vg734x3u/1/embedded/result/).

Thank you!

Comment: Can you make 1 clear example? The description you gave in the text does not match what is visible in the fiddle (no overlay visible at any video). Is what you made maybe dependent on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I observed a typo when you prepend an anchor to each `p` element. `<a/>` shall be `</a>`. I also observed a semicolon is missing. If you run JSHint on the fiddle, you will see the problem.

Anyway check out this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/szchenghuang/vg734x3u/3/embedded/result/). It puts a link over each `iframe` by modifying the style sheet either. You can start from here and make the layout of your page prettier.